# Связать значение переменной по мере её увелечения с UI представлением

Tags: c#, wpf

Сделал следующий класс для хранения значений

```
public class StatTracker
{
     private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TrackerType, int> _stats;

     public StatisticSource()
     {
       _stats = new ConcurrentDictionary<TrackerType, int>();

       _stats.TryAdd(TrackerType.Public, 0);
       _stats.TryAdd(TrackerType.Private, 0);
     }

     public void AddOne(StatisticType type)
     {
       _stats[type]++;
     }
}

public enum TrackerType
{
  Public,
  Private,
  Uknown
}
```

Каким образом привязать значение int каждого элемента Dictionary к TextBlock, что бы при его изменении TextBlock тоже обновлялся? (C использованием MVVM). Так же не совсем понимаю, как сделать удобный доступ с этому самому значению, т.к поле Dictionary приватное.

Я пробовал сделать через событие (вызывать его каждый раз при вызове AddOne) и привязаться к нему во вьюмодели, но такой способ при интенсивном вызове метода создаёт нагрузку на цп, что нежелательно. Ещё была идея сделать через таймер и обновлять по интервалу, но обновление значений на вью идёт не плавно, а прерывисто, что не подходит.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще словарь? Он здесь плохо подходит, заводите класс со свойствами TrackerType и int и отображайте его коллекцию. Вообще в VM использовать ConcurrentDictionary не должно хотеться, т.к. она должна делать всё в одном потоке с GUI

Comment: @АндрейNOP Словарь для того, что бы был удобный доступ к этой самой коллекции. Если я от него избавлюсь, заведу коллекцию в VM, то я не совсем понимаю как потом в модели получать нужный элемент и с ним работать, место же, где они хранились, теперь убрано в ВМ

Comment: Значит заводите коллекцию для вывода в GUI и словарь для удобного доступа по ключу и кладите и туда и туда одни и те же элементы

Comment: @АндрейNOP а основной вопрос, это как привязаться к изменению этого самого элемента ( int переменной ) не подскажите? Сделать всё таки через ивент?

Comment: Как обычно, через имплементацию INotifyPropertyChanged